# HTTP POST request is not working(CustomerViewModel=null)

Tags: asp.net-core

I managed to register a customer.
HTTP POST request is not working.
But HTTP GET request which displays the current logged in Customer  details in a View.

[image: When HTTP POST request,i got this null value]
[image: When HTTP GET request,it is working]

[image: request body and headers]

Comment: Can you add the request body and headers to your question ?

Comment: yes like this, [
    {
      
       "Number":07707070,
       "Desc": "kajas"
    }
]

Comment: I added the request body and headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method expects an object of type CustomerViewModel but your client is sending an array of objects.

Change

```
[ { "Number":07707070, "Desc": "kajas" } ]
```

To

```
{ "Number":07707070, "Desc": "kajas" }
```